# Yii scope - filter by related Model

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join, yii

I have a Yii project, with Products, Categories, etc..

I'm trying to filter Product, by a list of categories, so I would like to get all the Products in some categories.

The Product model has a relation to the Category model:

```
...
'categories' => array(self::MANY_MANY, 'ProductCategory', 'product_product_category(product_id, category_id)'),
...
```

My Product Model has the following named scope:

```
public function category($categoryWid){
    $category = ProductCategory::model()->findByWid($categoryWid); // wid is a custom id
    $all = $category->children_ids;

    $this->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith(array(
        'with'=>array(
            'categories'=>array(
                'condition' => "categories.id IN ($all)"
            )),
    ));
    return $this;
}
```

When I try to call this scope the following way:

```
Product::model()->category($categoryWid)->count();
```

It generates the following SQL.

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT `t`.`id`) 
FROM `product` `t`  
LEFT OUTER JOIN `product_product_category` `categories_categories` 
    ON (`t`.`id`=`categories_categories`.`product_id`) 
LEFT OUTER JOIN `product_category` `categories` 
    ON (`categories`.`id`=`categories_categories`.`category_id`)
WHERE (status = 2) AND (categories.id IN (21,23,22,24,25))
```

My problem is the double JOINs. So it's adding a second JOIN with the `with` method.

What do I have to change in the scope to use only the relation based JOIN, and achieve the filtering?

Answer (score 1):

This criteria helped for now:

```
$this->getDbCriteria()->mergeWith(array(
    'together' => false,
    'with'=>'categories',
    'condition' => "categories.id IN ($all)"
));
```

Comment: Upvote for finding your own, and posting the solution.